# In TypeScript, how to make the properties of an interface passed in the constructor optional in an interface of a parameter of a method?

Tags: typescript

I have a Logger class that can receive default optional values in the constructor:

```
interface Log {
  level: string
  scope: string
  source: string
  message: string
}

type LogDefaults = Partial<Log>
type LogInput = Log

class Logger {
  constructor(private defaults: LogDefaults = {}) {}

  public log(log: LogInput): void {
    console.log({ ...this.defaults, ...log })
  }
}
```

I want that the properties the user pass as "defaults" in the constructor are optionals in the log method.

Is there a way to define the "LogInput" type so the only required properties are those not provided in "LogDefaults" at runtime?

This should work:

```
const logger = new Logger()
logger.log({
  scope: 'my-scope',
  source: 'my-souce',
  level: 'info',
  message: 'my message'
})
```

This should work too:

```
const logger = new Logger({ scope: 'my-scope', source: 'my-souce' })
logger.log({ 
    level: 'info',
    message: 'my message'
})
```

This should NOT work (missing required "source" property):

```
const logger = new Logger({ scope: 'my-scope' })
logger.log({ 
    level: 'info',
    message: 'my message'
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be solved using [generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html).
[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgDIHsDmyDeAoZZAGwgDcIiAuZAZzClEwNoXQAcJq6GQnCb0AVyhIu9RswC2EGjTiZOtcbzwBfPHgRE4stFgVQAPABVkEAB6QQAExrIACnChhgcIoYyYAfF9zNWINyCCGDoUAAUbAykcJDI1hDwgkRgNAD81MYAlLjqzGyCAEZEwAjEWOFEWNQA8pLAYB5YADTIANYQAJ7oMMjGvgBkDk4ubk3eOfiEhAECJAB0VZjhOMjz62AAFsA08wlJKTSt64tYyKpZzOp5s2DlmAYAjMgAvMggEADueg-Q4ZdLJ6nZZTFjsRQAckknQAtDRWBwIc1mAJhKJkFDYaikEjmCRyFQMaAYOhcYRpLJ5JDocgKXIFBC1JdNOhAndAdAAEyvd5fH4GFZgjjUTFwhEQJG0IQialYoQ484A-Rc4GC5iEfEUEXE0nI6a0mT02UGykMpkaW73AwAZh5H2+ngFq3h4JF0LF4Ihio0eAA9L7kAABVIwiwcEKhqBQMJStEoHa0nY0CQcqDW1WrdXEMhaokgElk6Z0qluzomo2Mi4af1KYBEIjINxVT52ULIdDkKPABJ4VPppYrFHi0sexF62MykfYiXjzWEiE6wvFhSl8tUytZIA)

```
interface Log {
  level: string
  scope: string
  source: string
  message: string
}

class Logger<T extends Partial<Log>> {
  constructor(private defaults?: T) {}

  public log(log: Omit<Log, keyof T> & Partial<Log>) {
    console.log({ ...this.defaults, ...log })
  }
}

const logger1 = new Logger()
logger1.log({
  scope: 'my-scope',
  source: 'my-souce',
  level: 'info',
  message: 'my message'
})

const logger2 = new Logger({ scope: 'my-scope', source: 'my-souce' })
logger2.log({ 
    level: 'info',
    message: 'my message'
})

const logger3 = new Logger({ scope: 'my-scope' })


// @ts-expect-error source is missing
logger3.log({ 
    level: 'info',
    message: 'my message'
})

// still allows to override
logger3.log({
  scope: 'my-scope',
  source: 'my-souce',
  level: 'info',
  message: 'my message'
})
```

Edit: updated with suggestion from @Axnyff

Comment: `public log(log: Omit<Log, keyof LogType> & Partial<LogType>): void {` This can be probably an improvement as you want to be able to override a default property, I guess from the code